# When would I change my Ripple client's Web Socket IP and Blob vault URL?

Tags: ripple, ripple-client

What are the scenarios (value-add businesses) that would get users to edit the default ripple client and use a custom

- Web Socket IP: Port
- Blob vault URL

Why even make this a configuration option?  What is the envisioned benefits?  Is this related to a "gateway"?

Comment: @Downvoter / Closer: [According to meta Ripple questions are on topic](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/335/1878) .  Please provide constructive feedback for the down vote.

Answer (score 4):

The blob vault URL lets you choose who you trust to hold your wallet. While the wallet is encrypted, the organization that holds your wallet could attempt to brute force your password with the only limits being their computational resources.

The selection of web socket IP and port allows you to choose what Ripple server you want to connect to. The plan is to eventually let you have multiple servers saved in your wallet.

These choices have to do with how your client connects to the Ripple network and finds out your account information and annotations. It is not related to a choice of gateways, what IOUs you wish to hold, and so on.

Comment: Hmm, I kind of thought that "the cloud is my blob vault". So currently is https://blobvault.payward.com is taken down, my wallet is gone unless I saved it (in my local browser cache?)

Comment: Yes, your wallet would be gone unless you saved it someplace else. Note that this won't cause you to lose your funds -- your funds aren't stored in the wallet. (Make sure your account secret is stored somewhere safe!)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If someone gets my wallet do they automatically have access to my funds, or do they also need the secret key separately?

Comment: @Manish: It depends what you mean by "gets my wallet". If you mean they get the wallet *file*, then no. It's encrypted. If you mean they get the wallet *data*, then yes. The secret is stored in the wallet. The wallet is encrypted with the user name and password, so someone who somehow got your wallet without knowing the password would find it useless to them. (Unless they were able to brute force the password.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The username and password is what the Ripple client calls "Wallet name" and "Passphrase"? Is this part of the Ripple protocol, or is this just a client feature (so another client could use a different scheme)?

Comment: @Manish: It's just a client feature. Wallets are entirely client side.