# How do I backup my Ripple wallet?

Tags: ripple, backup

Ripple uses a Blob Vault structure to hold the wallet, but it currently resides on one centralized endpoint. [It might be prudent to back up your wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8004/when-would-i-change-my-ripple-clients-web-socket-ip-and-blob-vault-url/8006?noredirect=1#comment11831_8006).

How is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to backup/save, both can be found in the client under "`Wallet -> Security`".

The first and most important is your "secret key". Your public key is your ripple address that is `r0123456789ABCDEabcde`, your secret key is in a similar format but starts with '`s`', something like `s0123456789ABCDEabcde`. Write this down or save it somewhere safe. With just this your funds and trust lines can be recovered into a new wallet.

The other thing to save is your wallet. It's stored encrypted and contains your contacts as well as your secret key. The client will let you make an explicit copy into a local file that you can save as you wish. As with the secret key you do this via "Wallet->Security" in the client.

On account creation (and whenever you login) you can set the "Fetch wallet from" option to one of "Payward", "Payward and Local Browser" or "Local Browser". The middle option, both, is the default. It means that an encrypted copy of your wallet is stored at https://blobvault.payward.com (seen/set on the Advanced->Options page) **and** somewhere in your browser (?where?). The payward option allows you to access your wallet from any device and the local copy makes you not depend on payward being up/accessible at all times.

Comment: With respect to the "fetch wallet from" options, see http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7849/what-do-the-fetch-wallet-options-when-opening-a-ripple-wallet-mean/8534#8534

Comment: I would like to backup the wallet in my Dropbox, not just "somewhere in my browser".

Comment: @ripper234, Read again: "make an explicit copy into a local file". I assume you know how to get local files to/from Dropbox.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the part about export, thanks.